# I have no/I don't have any

Tags: verbs, negation

What am I supposed to say if I want to say that I don't possess ssomething? here are some sentences I have trouble with:

1-I have nobody or I don't have anybody?

2-There isn't any sugar or there's no sugar?

3-I have no knives in my bag or I don't have any knives in my bag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All forms are perfectly fine.

> 1-I have nobody or I don't have anybody?

Both sound fine.

"I don't have anybody" sounds a little more natural whereas "I have nobody ..." sounds more natural if something follows it: "I have nobody to turn to".

Otherwise "I have no one" sounds more natural on its own.

> 2- There isn't any sugar or there's no sugar?

Both sound fine and natural.

> 3- I have no knives in my bag or I don't have any knives in my bag?

Both are fine. The second form is slightly more natural I would say.